# Allow all numbers and letters but only this special caracters (# ‘ () + - ? ! / & * »)

Tags: javascript, keycode

I want allow only numbers and letters and this special caracters (# ‘ () + - ? ! / & * ») in JavaScript.

For this moment i have only numbers and letters allow but i want a special caracters. ( # ‘ () + - ? ! / & * » )

```
    $("#test").keypress(function(e) {
        $("#error").remove();
        var k = e.keyCode,
        $return = ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32  || (k >= 49 && k <= 57));
          if(!$return) {
            $("<span/>",{
                "id" : "error",
                "html" : "No special caracters allow !"
            }).insertAfter($j(this));
            return false;
          }

    });
```

Thank you in advance for your fast reply.

Comment: How about on `keyUp` you take the processed string and validate. If it fails, you return previous value.

Comment: does this help: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: There are _a lot_ of questions regarding regex on Stackoverflow, did you try looking them up?

Comment: @Ido_f OP may not be aware of regular expressions or the ability to extract the *actual character* from the event

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be easier to use `e.key` instead, which will give you the actual character, and not the character code, and then you can check the character against a regular expression that contains the permitted characters:

```
const isOk = /[a-z0-9#‘)(+-?!\/&*»]/i.test(e.key);
if (!isOk) {
  // handle error
}
```

Comment: OP is using keyCodes. If approach has to integrate regex, he will have to change few things. Please highlight that as well

Comment: The only place he's using the `keyCode` is to check the character - by using `e.key` instead, there's no more need for `keyCode` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

`[a-zA-Z0-9\[#()+-?!&*‘»]*`

you can test it on https://regex101.com/r/sxrFqq/2

Comment: OP is using keyCodes. Care to explain how to integrate it with your regex?

Answer (score 0):

Simple regex:

```
/[a-z0-9\#\'\(\)\+\-\/\&\*\»]/gi
```